# Ballerina docker build won't generate cloud artifacts for given configurable variable

Tags: docker, ballerina

I have written a service in Ballerina and when I tried to build it using `bal build --cloud=docker`, I get the following warning even if the build is successful.

```
default value is not specified for the configurable variable `port`. cloud artifacts will not be generated for this variable
```

Below is a sample code that gives this warning.

```
import ballerina/http;

configurable int port = ?;
service / on new http:Listener(port) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ballerina C2C extension currently only retrieves variables available at build time when building and generating the artifacts.

If you provide the `port` value at build time in above sample you will find the generated `Dockerfile` updated with the provided port exposed.